# How to dispose of date picker when reinitialising kendo ui object

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik

I am having to create my own form for creating a Kendo Scheduler event.

The built-in form has a feature whereby if the isAllDay checkbox is ticked the datetimepickers become just datepickers and visa-versa...

I have the following

```
 <div style="width:300px">
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="start">Start</label>
      <input id="start" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="end">End</label>
      <input id="end" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="isAllDay">
      <input type="checkbox" id="isAllDay" name="isAllDay" onchange="isAllDayChanged()"> Anytime</label>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    //Checkbox On Change Functions
    function isAllDayChanged() {
        setDateTimePickers();
    }

    //Set Datetime pikers with or without time
    function setDateTimePickers() {
        if($('#isAllDay').prop('checked')) {
            // create DateTimePicker from input HTML element for start and end datepickers
            $("#start").kendoDatePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
            $("#end").kendoDatePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
        } else {
            // create DatePicker from input HTML element for start and end datepickers
            $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
            $("#end").kendoDatePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setDateTimePickers();
    };
  </script>
```

On inital pageload the start and end inputs are inialised as datetimepickers. When the checkbox is checked a datepicker appears within the datetimepicker instead of replacing the datetimepicker.

How do I drop the element and reinitialise it as required?

UPDATE

Based on The_Black_Smurf's answer I updated my script to...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        //initalise start and end as DateTimePickers
        $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
        $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });

    });

    function isAllDayChanged() {
        setDateTimePickers();
    }

    //Set Datetime pikers with or without time

    function setDateTimePickers() {
        if ($('#isAllDay').prop('checked')) {
            // isAllDay has been checked get rid of initial DateTimePicker and re-initialise as DatePicker
            // do this for both start and end elements
            var kendoDateTimePicker = $("#start").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
            kendoDateTimePicker.destroy();
            $("#start").empty();
            $("#start").kendoDatePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
            var kendoDateTimePicker = $("#end").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
            kendoDateTimePicker.destroy();
            $("#end").empty();
            $("#end").kendoDatePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
        } else {
            // isAllDay is not checked get rid of DatePicker and re-initialise as DateTimePicker
            // do this for both start and end elements
            var kendoDatePicker = $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker");
            kendoDatePicker.destroy();
            $("#start").empty();
            $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
            var kendoDatePicker = $("#end").data("kendoDatePicker");
            kendoDatePicker.destroy();
            $("#end").empty();
            $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
                value:new Date()
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Results are still the same... the new kendo element is initalies inside of the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Fixed.... I now have a wrapping div around the inputs and these are the element I empty. I then recreate the input and then initalise them as datetimepicker or datepicker.

```
    <div style="width:300px">
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="start">Start</label>
      <div id="startDiv">
        <input id="start" style="width: 100%;" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="end">End</label>
      <div id="endDiv">
        <input id="end" style="width: 100%;" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label for="isAllDay">
      <input type="checkbox" id="isAllDay" name="isAllDay" onchange="isAllDayChanged()"> Anytime</label>
    </div>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    //Checkbox On Change Functions
    function isAllDayChanged() {
        setDateTimePickers();
    }

    function setDateTimePickers() {
    if ($('#isAllDay').prop('checked')) {
        // isAllDay has been checked get rid of initial DateTimePicker and re-initialise as DatePicker
        // do this for both start and end elements
        var kendoDateTimePicker = $("#start").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
        kendoDateTimePicker.destroy();
        $("#startDiv").empty();
        $("#startDiv").append('<input id="start" />');
        $("#start").kendoDatePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
        var kendoDateTimePicker = $("#end").data("kendoDateTimePicker");
        kendoDateTimePicker.destroy();
        $("#endDiv").empty();
        $("#endDiv").append('<input id="end" />');
        $("#end").kendoDatePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
    } else {
        // isAllDay is not checked get rid of DatePicker and re-initialise as DateTimePicker
        // do this for both start and end elements
        var kendoDatePicker = $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker");
        kendoDatePicker.destroy();
        $("#startDiv").empty();
        $("#startDiv").append('<input id="start" />');
        $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
        var kendoDatePicker = $("#end").data("kendoDatePicker");
        kendoDatePicker.destroy();
        $("#endDiv").empty();
        $("#endDiv").append('<input id="end" />');
        $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
    }
}

    $(document).ready(function () {
        //initalise start and end as DateTimePickers
        $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
        $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
            value:new Date()
        });
    };
  </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Every kendo widget have a [destroy](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datepicker#methods-destroy) method that will clear all the support related to the widget.  Once you've call the `destroy` method, you can empty the DOM element and you'll be able to recreate a new widget with that element if you need to.

Here's a sample code that will turn a kendoDatePicker into a kendoDateTimePicker:

```
var kendoDatePicker = $("#start").data("kendoDatePicker");
kendoDatePicker.destroy();
var widget = $("#start").closest(".k-widget");
var parent = widget.parent();

widget.remove();
parent.append("<input id=\"start\" />");

$("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({...});
```

**UPDATE**

I forgot to mention... some kendo widget will be wrapped inside new DOM elements (and this is the case for the datePicker and dateTimePicker).  So this mean that the element you had used as reference won't be the root of the element anymore.  From there, you'll have to find the root of the widget (usually, the closest parent with the `k-widget` class) and replace that node.  My updated example will give you an idea of the logic.

Comment: I looked as destroy but the documentation says it does not remove it from the DOM.   I've tried your code... see my update... but still have the same thing happening.